# apply() works not as expected

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to get a hold on how the apply function works. Here is what I tried:

```
df = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5), x2=c(1,2,3,4,5))
apply(df$x2, 2, function(x) x*2) #doesn't work
apply(df["x2"], 2, function(x) x*2) #works
apply(df[,2], 2, function(x) (x*2)) #doesn't work
apply(df[2], 2, function(x) x*2) #works (suprisingly)
apply(df[2,], 1, function(x) x*2) #works, but gives me vertical vector
apply(df[2,], 2, function(x) x*2) #works; this gives me the output I expected in line above
```

Questions (as idicated by comments):

- Why doesn't line 2 work although line 3 does?
- Why can I use [2,] to refer to row 2 (line 6), but cannot use [,2] to refer to column 2 (line 4), but have to use [2] (line 5) instead?
- In line 6 I expected to get what I got from line 7: row 2 (with double values) in a row. Why didn't I get this from line 6, I indicated row with
  MARGIN=2?

Comment: You should read `help("[")`. Basically, `apply` needs input that is an array or something that can be regarded as "matrix-like" (a data.frame). Some of your subsetting examples return a data.frame, others do not. This is related to the default value of the `drop` parameter of `[` and `[[`. Again, study the documentation.

Comment: And read the "Value" section in the manual of `apply` (`?apply`) for the third question.

Comment: Your example is bad because both cols are the same: try `df = data.frame(x=1:5, x2=6:10)` then you can identify better what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` needs to be used on something with a dimension of positive length. For simplicity some Object that has rows and columns.

That's why you have `margin 1, 2`. Standing for the row-wise and col-wise operation.

Check your Input values like this:

```
dim(df["x2"])
dim(df[,2]) #this is null, so it does not work
```

`df[,2]` gives you a vector same as `df$x2`. A vector does not have rows and cols. Therefore not working with `apply`.

In order to understand what you are doing wrong:

Type `?"["` into your console and read everything. Also play around... what you are already doing!

Have a closer look at the `drop` argument.

Lastly with `df[2,]` your subsetting a single row. It's still a dataframe.
Check `dim(df[2,])`

```
apply(df[2,], 1, function(x) x*2) #works, but gives me vertical vector
apply(df[2,], 2, function(x) x*2) #works; this gives me the output I expected in line above
```

The reason you don't get the same output. Is the WHOLE reason why `apply` exists. Please read `?apply` to understand.

When you have questions after reading the two mentioned resources, feel free to ask more.

Here is a little example:

```
m <- matrix(1:9,nrow=3)
m
apply(m,1,max) #row-wise max value
apply(m,2,max) #col-wise max value
```

Comment: Thanks for that; and also thanks everyone else, unfortunatelly there can only be one accepted answer..

Answer (score 1):

**Why doesn't line 2 work although line 3 does?**

`df$x2` is a vector i.e. `c(1,2,3,4,5)` whereas `df["x2"]` is a data frame with just one column. The vector has no second dimension to apply over. See `?'[']` in R for details of how subsetting works, this isn't really related to the apply function

**Why can I use [2,] to refer to row 2 (line 6), but cannot use [,2] to refer to column 2 (line 4), but have to use [2] (line 5) instead?**
Again, see the subsetting help page, but `df[,2,drop=FALSE]` is probably what you need.

**In line 6 I expected to get what I got from line 7: row 2 (with double values) in a row. Why didn't I get this from line 6, I indicated row with MARGIN=2?**
The **value** section of `?apply` explains the dimensions that you can expect as output from a call to apply:

> If each call to FUN returns a vector of length n, then apply returns an array of dimension c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN]) if n > 1. If n equals 1, apply returns a vector if MARGIN has length 1 and an array of dimension dim(X)[MARGIN] otherwise.

In this case we see that:

`> dim(df[2,])
 # [1] 1 2`

and so:

`apply(df[2,], 1, function(x) x*2)`

has `n=2` and `dim(df[2,])[1]=1`, so you should expect an output with dimensions `c(2,1)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is subsetting:

First:
`df$x2` and df[, 2] are different from `df["x2"]` and df[2], as the former return a `numeric` vector, the latter return a `data.frame`.

Second:
`df[2, ]` returns the second row of your `data.frame`. If you use `MARGIN = 1` you go through the rows, each row is represented as a (named) vector of length equal to the number of columns in your `data.frame`. 
If you use `MARGIN = 2` you go through the columns, again, each column is represented as a (named) vector of length equal to the number of rows in your `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at each type and dimension of the expression

```
> typeof(df$x2)
[1] "double"
> dim(df$x2)
NULL

> typeof(df["x2"])
[1] "list"
> dim(df["x2"])
[1] 5 1

> typeof(df[, 2])
[1] "double"
> dim(df[, 2])
NULL

> typeof(df[2])
[1] "list
> dim(df[2])
[1] 5 1

> typeof(df[2, ])
[1] "list"
> dim(df[2,])
[1] 1 2
```

The line 2 does not work because you try to apply function to variable which has NULL dimension. (`dim(X) must have positive length`). The rest is similar. You must keep attention on the type of the expression in apply. I recommend you to simply print values to check if there are properly for the apply function.